# Vue - Multiple optional router parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to build a component with multiple (optional) search options.

The path can be any of the following:

- my-site.com/gallery
- my-site.com/gallery/search+keyword
- my-site.com/gallery/140
- my-site.com/gallery/search+keyword/140/page/10

or any other combinations

this is what my route looks like

```
const galleryPageRoute = {
  path: '/gallery/:search?/:photocat?/:page(page\/\\d+)?',
  component: Gallery,
  name: 'Gallery',
  props: route => (Object.assign(route.params, { photocat: route.params.photocat, search: route.params.search, page: pageFromPath(route.path) }))
}
```

This is how I'm setting the parameters in my component

```
props: {
    page: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    photocat: {
      required: false
    },
    search: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },

filterCat(catid) {
      this.$router.push({name:'Gallery', params:{
        search: this.search ? this.search : undefined, 
        photocat: catid+'/'
      }});
    },

handleSubmit(result) {
      this.$router.push({name:'Gallery', params:{
        search: result.name,
        photocat: this.photocat ? this.photocat : undefined
      }});
    },
```

What's happening right now is if the search param is absent, 140 in the above example is getting considered as the search parameter and hence the prop "search" in my component is getting this value, however, as you can see in the `filterCat()` that this id has been set for the property photocat

Comment: Because https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/5141def3a21da479c2858c0d70db3cb438c3b7d0/dist/vue-router.js#L472

Comment: What can I do to make this work?

Comment: redesign or use a placeholder? `search: "s:" + this.search ? this.search : undefined,`

Comment: Create one route `/gallery/(:catId(\\d+))?` - category id parameter is numeric and optional. Pass search and page as query params. Example `/gallery/140?search=test&page=1`. To navigate to the route, use `this.$router.push({name:'Gallery', params:{catId: this.photocat ? this.photocat : ''}, query: {search: 'test', page: 1}});`. To access the query params, use `this.$route.query.search` and `this.$route.query.page`

Answer (score 0):

For match anything with `vue-router`, you should use the following syntax ([docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js#L22)):

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/' },
    // asterisk can match anything
    { path: '/asterisk*' },
    // asterisk can match anything like params
    { path: '/asterisk/*' },
  ]
})
```